# Nine togglers, one truth teller, and only a single question

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

You are standing in front of ten people, one of which is a *truth-teller* while the other nine are *togglers* . 
(A *toggler* is a person who toggles between *the-truth* and *the-lie* for every question asked.)
You have no clue who the truth-teller is and who the togglers are.

You are given the chance to ask **one and only one** question to **any, but only one** of the ten people.
From the provided answer you must be able to deduce with **certainty** the identity of the truth teller.

**Question:** So what is that question you will be asking?

Comment: presumably the people all know who are togglers and who is the truth teller, and you know that?

Comment: Do togglers know in which state their fellow togglers are?

Comment: @Ewan, was your question ever answered somewhere (and maybe subsequently deleted)?  It's pretty important to the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Which people here are truth-tellers"?

If the person you asked is a truth teller, he will indicate himself.

If he is a toggler in "truth" mode, he will indicate the truth teller.

If he is a toggler in "lie" mode, he will indicate the 9 togglers (this is my interpretation of telling "the-lie", and note they only toggle after each question and this is a single question). But as you know there is only one truth teller you know it must be the unindicated person.

Comment: Very nice. I guess in any case, you can be sure that the truth teller is the person that is classified like no other, similar to your last sentence.

Comment: Strictly speaking, they could lie by pointing out five people out of the 10.

Comment: @GlenO I would interpret 5 out of 10 as telling "partial truth", rather than "the-lie" as specified in OP. But you're right it's a matter of interpretation!

Comment: lie is often defined as something that is not true. so both partial or impartial truth is a lie and your method fails, becuase there is no surity  that he may point a correct person or a wrong person.

Comment: @ADG Yes, I agree that is one possible interpretation. My answer relies on a stricter definition of lie.

Comment: @IanF1 What if he says no-one? Seems like a fully blown lie to me.

Comment: A sentence that is false is a lie. That "partial truth" does not make sense.

Comment: Fair enough. Like i said, it was my interpretation of the scenario, YMMD.

Answer (score 4):

"If I asked you another question immediately after this, and then I pointed to another person in your group and asked 'Are they the truth-teller?', who could I point to in order for you to say 'yes'?"

Makes use of the fact that the togglers always alternate between truth and lie.

Comment: If he starts in lying mode then his answer to the third question would be any one person that is not the truth teller, he is going to lie about that statement and name any other person which could still leave you with a false answer.

Comment: @Poelie - I suppose that is a possibility. It's easily fixed, though. I'll update.

Comment: I highly doubt he would understand your qustion :D.(the person) Please explain in detail (I can't get it sorry)