# What is the best name for true-tellers, liars and normals

Tags: logical-deduction, liars, puzzle-history

In the world exists a lot of puzzles based on variations of true-tellers, liars and normals (sometimes lies, sometimes not). There are plenty of names for these characters, for example see the questions (or many others similar around the Internet):

[Knights and jokers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/593/knights-and-jokers)

[Island inhabitants: Who lies and who tells the truth?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8926/island-inhabitants-who-lies-and-who-tells-the-truth?lq=1)

[Nine togglers, one truth teller, and only a single question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/13141/nine-togglers-one-truth-teller-and-only-a-single-question?rq=1)

[Truths, Lies, and Xors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23819/truths-lies-and-xors?rq=1)

What is the most **correct** name for this puzzle and the characters?

What is the most **common** name for this puzzle and the characters?

What is the most **popular** name for this puzzle and the characters?

I know, this question demands answers strongly based on opinion, but still I would like to know, what do you think and why.

Because:

I believe a lot of scientific/popular literature about this logic puzzles exists, and maybe in this literature is some common/correct name suggested.

Also the first historical appearance of these puzzles could be the clue.

Comment: In Raymond Smullyan’s classic books, they’re called *knights*, *knaves*, and *normals*.  At least *knights* and *knaves* seem pretty ideal: widespread, unambiguous, and easy to say.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine That is funny. I have red this book in different language and translation was more close to "true-tellers, liars and normals". So this is really interesting point for me. You can create an answer.

Comment: Interesting!  What language was it, and what were the translations?  I’m not sure this is comprehensive enough to be a good answer — I’ll wait to see what other answers are posted, and then possibly post this later if it’s not subsumed by something better first.

Comment: Puzzles of this type also show up in some Martin Gardner books (from the 1960s), and they have been popular for a long time at mathematical highschool competitions in the USSR.

Comment: Answering the third question in bold.... Just do a Google ngram search to figure. Apart from that, there is no accurate way to determine which is more popular.

Comment: The Wikipedia article for this sort of puzzle is titled [Knights and Knaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_and_Knaves), and cites Smullyan as coining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be no right answer for this question since it is subjective.

The oft-used adjectives are [Knights and Knaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_and_Knaves) for truth-tellers and liars respectively (as [Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4234/peter-lefanu-lumsdaine) and [alexwlchan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4692/alexwlchan) pointed out). Often the normals are described as such - since they are usually not normal per se, but rather do something like lie or tell the truth according to a uniform random variable (are "unpredictables").

I quite like these somewhat archaic English terms **soothsayers**, **mythomaniacs**, and **quixotics** for truth-tellers, liars, and unpredicatables.

We could also try to give them individual names; some with somewhat relevant meanings one could use are as follows (I'm sure there are more).

For the truth-teller:

- Alethea (Greek: aletheia = truth)
- Amin (Arabic: amin = truthful)
- Sati (Sanskrit: sati = truthful)
- Sidika (Turkish: sidika = truth)
- Verity (English: verity = truth)

For the liar:

- Bellona (Latin: bellare = fight)
- Drake (Old Norse: draki = dragon)
- Lileth (Akkadian: lilitu = of the night)
- Mark / Marcus / Martin (Greek: Mars = the god of war)

For the normal / unpredictable

- Alf / Alfred (Old Norse: Alfr = elf)
- Caprice (English capricious = unpredictable)
- Dougal (Gaelic dubh = dark", gall "stranger")
- Nemo (Latin: nemo = nobody)
- Peter (Greek: petros = stone)
- Thomas (Aramaic: a'oma' = twin)

Or how about being a little tongue in cheek and going for something like: Frank (to be frank); Phoebe (fibber) or Lyle (liar); and Norman (normal).